# How to replace this HTML snippet in some text?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.NET 4.5 and C#

I want to replace :

```
<div style="page-break-after:always"><span style="display:none">&nbsp;</span></div>
```

in a string with:

```
<br style="page-break-after: always;" />
```

I have tried:

```
//string strContent is a string that contains HTML content
strContent = strContent.Replace("<div style='page-break-after:always'><span style='display:none'>&nbsp;</span></div>", "<br style='page-break-after: always;' />");
```

But with no success. Obviously I am missing something simple.

Help hugely appreciated.

Comment: The difference is single quotes and double. Use double quotes with escape sequence

Comment: Remember `String.Replace` makes an *exact* (except, optionally, case) match. One space or quote changed in the input and there will be no replacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mixed up the " and ':

```
strContent = strContent
    .Replace("<div style=\"page-break-after:always\">" + 
             "<span style=\"display:none\">&nbsp;</span></div>",
             "<br style=\"page-break-after: always;\" />");
```